# Android not sending json string

Tags: php, android, json, http-post

I am facing the problem where i am sending an jsonstring, but the string is empty.

When i use this php code to see if i am recieving a string and what i get:

```
POST: 
Array
(
)



 GET: 
Array
(
    [data] => 
)
```

This is my Android code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myserver.nl/locatie.php?data="); 
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); 

        // Create json object here... 
        json = new JSONObject(); 
        try { 
            json.put("id", "0612838"); 
            json.put("longitude", "-143.406417"); 
            json.put("latitude", "32.785834"); 
            json.put("timestamp", "10-10 07:56"); 

        } catch (JSONException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        /// create StringEntity with current json obejct 

        try { 
        se = new StringEntity(json.toString()); 
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")); 
        httppost.setEntity(se); 

        try { 
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
```

Does anybody see what i am doing wrong?

Comment: try to read the raw http data coming from the android app..

Comment: I had similar problem in one of the project I have done.. Then the PHP developer solved it by using the raw data...  I don't have any exp. in PHP so cant help there. :(

Comment: @Babboe : how you retrieving in PHP

Comment: file_put_contents('dump.txt', "POST: \n" . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n\n\n GET: \n" . print_r($_GET, true));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NameValuePair`:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://www.myserver.nl/locatie.php");

    json = new JSONObject(); 
    try { 
        json.put("id", "0612838"); 
        json.put("longitude", "-143.406417"); 
        json.put("latitude", "32.785834"); 
        json.put("timestamp", "10-10 07:56"); 

    } catch (JSONException e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 

    /// create StringEntity with current json obejct 

    try { 
    se = new StringEntity(json.toString()); 

        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", se));

        httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));


        System.out.println("send about to do post");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
        System.out.println("send post done");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
           ....


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

**Server side**

```
  if (isset($_POST["data"]))
  {                                                                                                                                       
  // Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.
  $sub = json_decode($_POST"data"],true);
  .....
  }
```

Comment: No i need this exact json string for my asp.net file. It needs t be exact like this jsonstring

Comment: if you send only one jsonstring, use only one `BasicNameValuePair` with tag, like: nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonstring", se));

Comment: Will this give me {"id":"0612833398","longitude":"-143.406417","latitude":"32.785834",
                                                   "timestamp":"10-10 07:56"} when i do the php code?

Comment: There's something wrong can you look at this pastebin code? http://pastebin.com/Z8tpFgWH

Comment: i am getting an error or at nvps.add that "se" must be a string. if i change that. the String se must be a String Entity

Comment: JUst use `String se = json.toString();` instead `StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());`

Comment: @Babboe : use `nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", json.toString()));` instead of `nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", se));`

Comment: well, Exception type? where?

Comment: look it works but..    [data] => {"timestamp":"10-10 07:56","id":"0612838","longitude":"-143.406417","latitude":"32.785834"}
Why is the timestamp as first. i need the id, than longitude, latitude and timestamp

Comment: As you know, Json Object doesn't sort stuff depend to your initiation flow. On server side you can create `$list = array(); ... and put there what you want`